# Error when uploading mySQL file

Tags: mysql

After i used the new answer i uploaded the file and this is what i get now.

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` ( ) INSERT INTO `games` (`name`, `creatorid`, `gameid`, `id`, `plays) VALUES ('בדיקה', 'לא ידוע', 1,1,0) CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gamewall` ( `userid` int(11) NOT NULL, `reason` text NOT NULL, `comment` text NOT NULL, `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `bannedbyid` int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bans_IP` ( `IP` mediumtext NOT NULL, `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `bannerid` int(11) NOT NULL, `reason` mediumtext NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buysell` ( `buysell` int(11) NOT NULL, `sellerid` int(11) NOT NULL, `price` int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `competitions` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` mediumtext NOT NULL, `startedbyid` int(11) NOT NULL, `descripti[...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') 

INSERT INTO `games` (`name`, `creatorid`, `gameid`, `id`, `plays) VALUES
('' at line 3
```

Comment: If you don't understand just reply saying you don't understand and what part!

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking `edit` button  at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Before you continue using a database, read about database normalization! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: ... and also read about the different datatypes mysql supports. not everything is a mediumtext (in fact, that's one of the datatypes used less) - I haven't seen a username with 16,777,215 characters so far (also not a minute)...

Comment: Aww.. i was looking for someone who could fix it..

Comment: please show a snippet of the data you are trying to upload.  After removing the second line `bannedReason mediumtext NOT NULL,`, I can run both of your `create table statements` with no error.

Comment: It says the SQL Query and i think thats the code its in the post now

Comment: I used the answer and this is what it gives me now

Comment: Ugh check the post its over the limit

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you have selected all the columns of your table but values are available for first `11` columns and you missed `)` in last

This code will fix your problem

```
INSERT INTO `accounts` (
   `Username`,
   `Password`,
   `Email`,
   `salt`,
   `Reebs`,
   `online`,
   `lastOnline`,
   `lastOnlineMinutes`,
   `lastOnlineHours`,
   `status`,
   `blurb`
)
VALUES
   (
      'AvatarLife',
      'df3ed1ad53c4cc2f3b5c6bdf04d33a9f094df53b',
      'fawrsnipng@gmail.com',
      'jBqnW?Dk9Epzpg4',
      '9223372036854775807',
      '1',
      '205',
      '26',
      '13',
      '',
      'Avatar Life is the only good life!')
```